# MYSQL how to group by specific value?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Let's say I have a table like this:

```
     id     |   amount
 -------------------------
     1      |    10 
     1      |    10   
     2      |    20   
     2      |    10   
     3      |    20   
     3      |    10   
     3      |    10   
     4      |    10
```

Let's say id **1** and **2** are special, I want to group them together and name it as **special**. Ids that are other than **1** and **2** should also not be grouped together. Lastly, I want to sum the amount. So, how to I get the result like this:

```
    type     |   total_amount
 -------------------------------
   special   |      50 
   3         |      40   
   4         |      10
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use a `case when` to transform `id`'s values into the ones you are after, and then apply a `sum()` function to get the aggregate:

```sql
select
  case 
    when id in (1, 2) then 'special'
    else cast(id as char)
  end as type,
  sum(amount) as total_amount
from <your_table>
group by 1
```

Answer (score 1):

please try this

```
SELECT 
    CASE
        WHEN id IN (1, 2) THEN 'special'
        ELSE CAST(id AS CHAR)
    END AS type, 
    SUM(amount) AS total_amount
FROM __table__
GROUP BY id
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also see separately each ID of special with the below code :

```
select case 
        when id in (1, 2) then 'Special'
        else id
       end type,
       id,
       sum(amount) total_amount
  from table
 group by 1,2
```

| type | id | amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| special | 1 | 20 |
| special | 2 | 30 |
| 3 | 3 | 40 |
| 4 | 4 | 10 |